# Использование условия and в django-filters

Tags: python, django

Библиотека django-filters по умолчанию фильтрует по критерию OR, как добавить критерий AND. На фронте это предполагаю будет выглядеть как чекбокс, как переопределить стандартное поведение при условии выбора чекбокса пользователем.

Сейчас мой вариант фильтрующий по OR
**filters.py**

```
class EmployeeFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    skills = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(queryset=Technology.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ['skills']
```

views.py

```
 class AccountList(AuthorizedMixin, ListView):
    """
        List of all employees
    """

    model = Employee
    template_name = 'employee_list.html'
    filter_class = EmployeeFilter

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        query = self.request.GET.get('q', None)  # Это часть отвечает за поиск по имени
        if query:
            object_list = self.model.objects.filter(

                Q(user__last_name__icontains=query)|
                Q(user__first_name__icontains=query)
             )
        else:
            object_list = self.model.objects.all()
        return object_list

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AccountList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['filter'] = EmployeeFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=self.get_queryset())
        return context
```

**template.html**

```
<form method='get'>
            <div class="input-group">
              {% render_field filter.form.skills class="form-control bg-light" %}
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-info" type="button">Go!</button>
              </span>
            </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: У меня Filter в Джанго как раз по умолчанию фильтрует по критерию `and`. А вот по `or` использую Q-выражения, как в вашем варианте

Comment: Странно, есть два пользователя . у одного два умения , у второго одно из этих двух. Выбираю в фильтре оба поля и получаю обоих пользователей.

Comment: ну попробуйте вместо Q-обьектов просто перечислить условия через запятую. Результат должен отличаться

Comment: В общем отказался от использования django-filters и сделал всю логику вручную. Спасибо за отклик.

Comment: вы можете просматривать запросы, сформированные Джанго фильтрами через django debugtoolbar